# My JButton wouldn't show if there's JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I have problem showing JButton when there's a JTextField.

I tried switching places of the JButton and JTextField like this:

From this:

```
TriangleSolution.add(SolutionTextArea);
TriangleSolution.add(SolutionExitButton);
```

To this:

```
TriangleSolution.add(SolutionExitButton);
TriangleSolution.add(SolutionTextArea);
```

But when I do that, the other components wouldn't show

> Blockquote

Here's the code:

```
JScrollPane ScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
JTextArea SolutionTextArea;
TriangleSolution = new JFrame();
            
Base = ("Base = " +ValueOfBase.getText());
Height = ("Height =" + ValueOfHeight.getText());    
                
String AreaOfTriangle = ("△ = Base * Height / 2");
                
SolutionTextArea = new JTextArea();
        
SolutionTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
SolutionTextArea.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
SolutionTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
SolutionTextArea.setEditable(false);
SolutionTextArea.setText(AreaOfTriangle + "\n" + "\n" + Base + "\n" + Height);
                
SolutionExitButton = new JButton("Exit");
SolutionExitButton.setBounds(500, 500, 100, 100);
SolutionExitButton.setFocusable(false);
SolutionExitButton.addActionListener(this);
                
TriangleSolution.add(SolutionExitButton);
TriangleSolution.add(SolutionTextArea);
                
                TriangleSolution.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
TriangleSolution.setVisible(true);
TriangleSolution.setResizable(false);
// TriangleSolution.setLocation(1200,100);
TriangleSolution.setSize(1000,1000);
TriangleSolution.setLayout(null);
```

Please help, I'm also learning this all by myself

Comment: use a `LayoutManager` like `BorderLayout`. Don't set absolute places for components.

Comment: I already tried that it works but I want to place the components to specific location

Comment: Still, `LayoutManager` is the way to go. There are a ton of those out there and some are more powerful than others

Comment: Well, how could I set the location if I'm using layout manager?

Comment: `TriangleSolution.setLayout(null);` isn't helping, but the "other" problem is, when you add your components, `TriangleSolution` is already making use of a layout manager, and by default, it's using a `BorderLayout`, which will only allow one component to be managed for each of the available slots

Comment: *"Well, how could I set the location if I'm using layout manager?"* - You're missing the point of layout managers.  Layout managers are intended to provide you means to "describe" the layout you want and the system then takes care of all the fiddle, annoying, time wasting work that it takes to make those layouts work on different platforms

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: _I want to place the components to specific location_ Try [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) (or `GroupLayout`) Note that there are also third party layout managers such as [MigLayout](https://www.miglayout.com/)